# Как найти все неиспользуемые методы в IDEA?

Tags: ide, java, intellij-idea

Как найти все неиспользуемые методы в моем проекте? Периодически вижу, что метод выделен серым, типа нигде не используется. А можно ли как-то найти все?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Я в таких случаях пользуюсь методом `Analyze | Inspect Code`.*

Естественно, что для анализа неиспользуемого кода должна быть включена опция **Unused declaration** в группе **Declaration redundancy.**

Answer (score 3):

Дополню: c версии CE11 действует такой способ:

"Analyze | Run Inspection by Name ... | Unused declaration"

Либо - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> → "Unused declaration"